# Move PDB to a new host

Tags: oracle, rman, oracle-12c

We're using Oracle 12c, and have two separate servers running Oracle, with a CDB with 2 PDBs.

What is the easiest way of getting the data from server A to server B, as a one-time job (not replication)?

So far I can imagine the following alternatives:

1. Do a TRANSPORTABLE RMAN backup, copy it to the second host, do a restore there
2. Do a datapump export, move it to the second host, restore there
3. Unplug the PDB, copy its xml-file and data to the second host, plug it in there

About alternative 3, I'm not even sure if it's a real option.
Which of these alternatives would be easiest to accomplish?

I've tried to read up on the Oracle documentation, but it's very verbose and not at all easy to comprehend (which I suppose is why they're selling so much support services).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3.

Unplug the PDB:

[Unplugging a PDB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_plug.htm#ADMIN13858)

`ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE salespdb UNPLUG INTO '/oracle/data/salespdb.xml';`

Copy the files (XML + database files), then perform the checks listed below:

[Plugging In an Unplugged PDB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_plug.htm#ADMIN13855)

Finally plug in the PDB:

[Examples of Plugging In an Unplugged PDB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_plug.htm#CEGHIEBE)

`CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE salespdb USING '/disk1/usr/salespdb.xml' 
  NOCOPY 
  TEMPFILE REUSE;`

Comment: Question of mine as I have read the same in various oracle docs. In order to use the datafiles from cdb1 into cdb2 (another host) I need to put them....where? Does it needs to be the same path? Or does they have to be in the path where the using clause points to?